# How to delete a Collection in LokiJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-modules, lokijs

I been working on LokiJS on Node recently, And I could'nt find a command that deletes the entire Collection itself,

I tried with these commands with an assumption it would exist, I could not find any docs/ samples to delete a collection.

`// let result = this.db.dropCollection(collectionName);
 // let result = this.db.removeCollection(collectionName);
 // let result = this.db.deleteCollection(collectionName);`

Other way around I know I can achieve the same by reading the file and removing the entire object, But is there a built-in LokiJS function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To delete a collection you need to use the `removeCollection()` method on the main Loki object. [See docs here](https://rawgit.com/techfort/LokiJS/master/jsdoc/Loki.html).

For example, if you have your Loki instance initialized like this:

```
const loki = require('lokijs');
const lokidb = new loki();

// Add a collection (that we will remove later)
let myCollection = lokidb.addCollection('myCollection');
```

Now `lokidb` is your main loki object, and this is the object that you need to execute the `removeCollection()` from.

```
// Let's remove the collection
lokidb.removeCollection('myCollection');

// * poof * ....
// myCollection is now gone

// To make sure that this deleting change is persisted (if necessary)
lokidb.saveDatabase();
```

I don't know exactly how you have your loki db set up, but hopefully this example helps.

Comment: I tried the same ,  but din't work, am i missing anything else ?

Comment: Can you share a full example of your code, on a code pen, or a gist?

Comment: Hey , i just found what the issue was ,  `lokidb.saveDatabase();` actually reflects the changes, infact i kept the autosave interval very less , still dint work - `lokidb.saveDatabase();`did the trick !! Thanks for the help !!

Comment: @MaheshKumaran Glad you figured that out. I added your step in case any others have issues with persistence and autoSave like you did. If you want, check the answer as solved to help others. :-)

Comment: Even with `db.card.findAndRemove({guid});
        await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            db.loki.saveDatabase((err) => err ? reject(err) : resolve());
        });

        console.log(db.card.find({guid}));` still doesn't work.